# preg_replace_callback() returns wrong arrays when multiple instances

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I have the following script which replaces `[amazon region=com asin=1234567]` in my string with `getAffiliateLink("com","1234567")` to trigger a PHP function and show a specific div:

```
$content = preg_replace_callback('/\[amazon region=([^\b]+) asin=([^\b]+)\]/', 'callback', $content);

 function callback ($matches) {
    print_r($matches);
    return getAffiliateLink("$matches[1]","$matches[2]");
 }

 echo $content;
```

Now this works perfectly.. until I have multiple instances of `[amazon region=com asin=1234567]` in my string, each with a different asin number.

Then I get the following print:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => [amazon region=com asin=B004QJ9458] [amazon region=com asin=B0080KWRI0] 
    [1] => com asin=B004QJ9458] [amazon region=com 
    [2] => B0080KWRI0 
)
```

It's obvious that something is going wrong here looking at the output above.How can I change my code so it works for different instances of the particular string?

Comment: Your `+` operators are being greedy, use `+?` to make them un-greedy.

Comment: @Sammitch Thanks, this seems to return a correct array. Now my PHP function is executed for the first instance, but returns notices for missing parameters for the next instances. Only the first time the function triggers correctly..

Comment: Nevermind my last reply, it works perfectly now! Thanks a lot, I learned something new!

Comment: @SenneVandenputte Have you checked my answer below?

Answer (score 0):

The `[^\b]` character class matches any char but a \x08 char (BACKSPACE).

You may fix the pattern using

```
$content = preg_replace_callback('/\[amazon region=(\S+) asin=(\S+)\]/', 'callback', $content);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/S51yn6).

The `\S+` matches 1 or more non-whitespace chars.